# Images completely out of alignment in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am new to HTML/CSS and have been working on a website by editing an existing template with HTML 5 responsive features. My workflow consisted of checking back and forth between the code and the Chrome browser.

After I finished the website and was happy with the results, I checked to see how everything was displaying in Firefox and Safari.

To my shock, I suddenly saw that in Firefox the images on a couple of pages were sent completely out of alignment to the far right of the browser (so much so, that I would have to use the horizontal scroller to see the images fully). Throughout the whole development process I had no such problems with Chrome.

However, subsequently I have seen that there are also more slight image display errors for the website in Chrome and Safari on the iPad.

So far I have looked through the questions on this site and also run the w3 online html and css validators. None of these things have worked.

Below I have provided the html of one of the affected images and the relevant css below that.

```
<figure>
   <img src="img/image.jpg" alt="Some text">
   <figcaption>Some Text
   </br>
   (Photo credit: Daniel Easterman)
  </figcaption>
</figure>


#main_article img
{

display: block; 
border: 0; 
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 20px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D0C1;
}

#main_article figcaption
{
line-height: 25px;
font-size:14px;
max-width:900px;
width:auto;
}
```

I hope someone can help me figure out why there is this discrepancy between chrome and firefox and what I can do to solve the problem so the images display nicely on both browsers. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You should link to a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem.

Comment: *"...and also run the w3 online html and css validators"* Please note that in the snippet here, you have a `</br>` tag that is invalid. The validator will only tell you what is wrong with the markup. You'll have to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at your code and can't find anything wrong.  Even tested it on jsFiddle.

The problem you're having must have something to do with whatever styling you have for [body] or [container], etc.

basically, you might want to provide the bigger picture so we can help.  Maybe share with us the entire style sheet, or whatever is relevant, perhaps the #main_article?

Another thing, is maybe firefox is not happy with custom elements and perhaps you should change figure and figcaption into classes instead (just a guess)

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for your help so far, I will provide more info in the "answer your question" section, as adding a comment is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

The full main article section is below. Also attached is a screenshot showing the problem in firefox.
[image: Firefox screenshot]

```
 #main_article 
{
position:relative;
width:auto;
max-width:900px;
margin: 0 auto 20px auto;

 }

#main_article h3 
{
margin:35px 0 0 0;
font-size:25px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D0C1;
padding: 20px 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width:auto;
float:left;
max-width:900px;
```

}

```
#main_article h4
{
line-height:25px;
width:auto;
float:left;
font-weight:900;
max-width:900px;
```

}

```
#main_article p
{
line-height:25px;
width:auto;
float:left;
font-weight:normal;
padding: 5px 0;
```

}

```
#main_article p a
{
    text-decoration:none;
color:#00bfff;
```

}

```
#main_article p a:hover
{ text-decoration:underline;}
```